# Problems with Cycles Baking!

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have a bit of a problem, I'm trying to bake out a normal and a AO Map from a hires model, And place it on a lowres model.

The problem I get is when i bake the normals, the whole thing is pixelated, And the AO just has Solid Black and white noise all over it, you can't even see the shadows.
Im guessing that noise is whats causing it on both maps, however I have no idea how to get around it.

Ive looked around for an answear, i found very little information on this issue, some said it may be due to overlapping UVS, but i have none overlapping. I even tried using smart UV, still looks the same.

Please someone help me, this is really annoying, Been running into this every time I'm trying to bake!

Im attaching a photo where I edited them together to show you the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: May you have hidden objects that could be overlayed to the object's faces? Could you show a picture of your baking setup&scene?

Comment: I am guessing here that you don't have smoothing on the face normal, and secondly you have the low res mesh on the high res mesh overlapped while baking the AO. ... AO baking does not work when you have the hi and low meshes overlapped. If your normals keeps giving you issue you may have to use the shrink wrap modifier. Try using the multires bake method instead it doesn't require you to overlap the mesh.

Comment: What do you mean by smoothing on the face normal? And about the low res and high res overlapping, i only have that because in the tutorial  I watched, that guy had them overlapping. And his result was perfect? Ive never tried the shrink wrap modifier, what exactly does it do? and is there anything i need to know, or do i just apply that? 
And I've never heard of the multires bake method either, is that part of cycles or blender render?

Comment: I will edit my post and attach an image of how my scene look.

Comment: I usually use blender internal to do the baking as it has not much difference to how it works. Multires requires that you sculpt your object into the shape you want and bake directly off the multires modifier. Overlapping specifically is used to bake highres mesh's normal onto lowres mesh. If you view the video in detail again, I am sure he did not bake the AO of the highres mesh while the lowres mesh is also occluding it. If you have the meshes overlapped while baking AO you will expect the rays to bounce between the 2 surfaces of the meshs and create the noise you see.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTGTUd0pCaQ watch this video on youtube on how to use the shrink wrap modifier.

Comment: To apply smoothing to your highres model do this, 1. Go into edit mode 2. Select all the faces 3. Hit the "W" key on the keyboard 4. Select "shade smooth" .... Do not select "smooth" or "Laplacian smooth" they are different operation and they affect your vertices instead.

Comment: Oh, well, i guess I'm going to do that next time, but as i have already finished the sculpting, i just wanna be able to fix this one! 
Well i just watched it, and as far as i can tell, he still has them overlapping, here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHmw783xreY . But the shrink wrap modifier, is that a possible solution for the normal map baking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33948/discussion-between-hawkenfox-and-user2866639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's what I found. Due to the way your hires model is made you do not have an initial starting point with a basic UV unwrap. So we have to go the cage projection route. Which is the same method you were trying to follow on the video tutorial you posted in the chat.

Attached is the file you sent me, I have manage to produce the normals and AO with no problems on my end. You can try out the blend file below. I have packed a copy of the bake I made. Also to the left of the baking models I have created a GLSL shading model using Blender Internal Materials.

You will need to create nodes holding the texture for Ambient Occlusion and Normals. On the file you will see a green frame and a red one on the node window. The Green one is the node you need to select and make active before baking the Ambient Occlusion. Likewise the Red on is the node which holds the normal texture you need to select before baking.

[image]

[DOWNLOAD - Here is the file](https://mega.nz/#!TNVXUYIA!AipEpwGUyI7hUyMDpjorY7nHG3gd0w9DYh5qLlj26a8).